# can't get data from dynamic multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `array` of names:

```
$groups = array
  (
      'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth'
  );
```

Then I create an array for each, and put 2nd level arrays into them:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($groups); ++$i) {
  $$groups[$i] = array ();
  array_push($$groups[$i], array('col1' => 'data', 'col2' => 'data'));
  array_push($$groups[$i], array('col1' => 'data2', 'col2' => 'data2'));
}
```

When I try to loop through and get any data, all I get is "Array".

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($groups); ++$i) {
  for($j = 0; $j < count($$groups[$i]); ++$j) {
    echo($$groups[$i][$j][0] . " - " .$$groups[$i][$j][1]);
}
```

I'm quite sure that the problem is the way I try to address those bottom level arrays, but can't figure out the right way.

P.S.: if I `var_dump` `$$groups[$i]` it returns everything, so the data is there.

Comment: You are not really creating a 3rd level because of the notation you use which is hard to read and error prone (`$$groups[$i]`).

Comment: @arkascha Well, in fact it's just two levels. var_dump returns `array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["col1"]=> string(3) "dat" ["col2"]=> string(3) "dat" } [1]=> array(2) { ["col1"]=> string(4) "dat2" ["col2"]=> string(4) "dat2" }}` for each `$$groups[$i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$$groups[$i]` doesn't do what you think it does, PHP interprets it as `($$groups)[$i]`. What you actually want is `${$groups[$i]}`. If you had error reporting on with notice level errors you'd see a lot of `NOTICE Array to string conversion on line number xx` messages. Take a look at the output of `get_defined_vars()` and you'll see you have an array called `Array`, instead of a set of arrays called `first`, `second` etc.

Also your indexes in the third level array are `col1` and `col2`, not `0` and `1`.

Try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($groups); ++$i) {
    ${$groups[$i]} = array ();
    array_push(${$groups[$i]}, array('col1' => 'data', 'col2' => 'data'));
    array_push(${$groups[$i]}, array('col1' => 'data2', 'col2' => 'data2'));
    // print_r(${$groups[$i]});
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($groups); ++$i) {
    for($j = 0; $j < count(${$groups[$i]}); ++$j) {
        echo(${$groups[$i]}[$j]['col1'] . " - " .${$groups[$i]}[$j]['col2']);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
data - data
data2 - data2
data - data
data2 - data2
data - data
data2 - data2
data - data
data2 - data2
data - data
data2 - data2
data - data
data2 - data2
data - data
data2 - data2
data - data
data2 - data2
```